# Get all the Child Elements and push it into array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I've a very complex JSON data with many children/ child  node. I am trying  a lot to flatten it so I that i solves my purpose.

I just need to take all the nested "children" and sub - children  and push them into a single array.

Please help me out,
 Below is my sample data,

```
{
  "path": "/root",
  "name": "Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b",
  "type": "folder",
  "children": [
    {
      "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/assets",
      "name": "assets",
      "type": "folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/assets/proxies.png",
          "name": "proxies.png",
          "type": "file"
        },
        {
          "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/assets/targets.png",
          "name": "targets.png",
          "type": "file"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/codgen-for-wsil-backend-esg",
      "name": "codgen-for-wsil-backend-esg",
      "type": "folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/codgen-for-wsil-backend-esg/assets",
          "name": "assets",
          "type": "folder",
          "children": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/codgen-for-wsil-backend-esg/index.md",
          "name": "index.md",
          "type": "file"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/index.md",
      "name": "index.md",
      "type": "file"
    },
    {
      "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/jwt-implementation-esg",
      "name": "jwt-implementation-esg",
      "type": "folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/jwt-implementation-esg/assets",
          "name": "assets",
          "type": "folder",
          "children": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/jwt-implementation-esg/index.md",
          "name": "index.md",
          "type": "file"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output is to be mapped based on the parent "name",

```
[
  {
    "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/assets/proxies.png",
    "name": "proxies.png",
    "type": "file"
  },
  {
    "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/assets/targets.png",
    "name": "targets.png",
    "type": "file"
  },
  {
    "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/codgen-for-wsil-backend-esg/assets",
    "name": "assets",
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/codgen-for-wsil-backend-esg/index.md",
    "name": "index.md",
    "type": "file"
  },
  {
    "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/index.md",
    "name": "index.md",
    "type": "file"
  },
  {
    "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/jwt-implementation-esg/assets",
    "name": "assets",
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/jwt-implementation-esg/index.md",
    "name": "index.md",
    "type": "file"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could recursively call the function on `children` like this:

- Use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) to loop through the array and flatten the array returned at each level.
- [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) each object to get `children` and [`rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) of the properties to separate variables.

  - Check if the object has `children`. If yes, return that object with `children: []` + recursively `transform` it's `children`
  - If no, return just the object in an array `[rest]`

```js
const input={path:"/root",name:"Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b",type:"folder",children:[{path:"/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/assets",name:"assets",type:"folder",children:[{path:"/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/assets/proxies.png",name:"proxies.png",type:"file"},{path:"/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/assets/targets.png",name:"targets.png",type:"file"}]},{path:"/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/codgen-for-wsil-backend-esg",name:"codgen-for-wsil-backend-esg",type:"folder",children:[{path:"/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/codgen-for-wsil-backend-esg/assets",name:"assets",type:"folder",children:[]},{path:"/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/codgen-for-wsil-backend-esg/index.md",name:"index.md",type:"file"}]},{path:"/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/index.md",name:"index.md",type:"file"},{path:"/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/jwt-implementation-esg",name:"jwt-implementation-esg",type:"folder",children:[{path:"/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/jwt-implementation-esg/assets",name:"assets",type:"folder",children:[]},{path:"/root/Through_5cd5553eb7f004432205cb6b/jwt-implementation-esg/index.md",name:"index.md",type:"file"}]}]};

function trasnform(array) {
  return array.flatMap(({ children, ...rest }) => {
    if(children)
      return [{ ...rest, children: [] }, ...trasnform(children)]
    else
      return [rest]
  })
}

console.log(trasnform(input.children))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function similar to this to flatten your data:

```js
function flatten(data) {
  const { path, name, type, children = [] } = data;
  const result = []; // you can add the parent data in the result if you want
  let queue = [...children];

  while (queue.length > 0) {
    const { path, name, type, children = []} = queue.shift();
    result.push({ path, name, type });
    queue = [...queue, ...children];
  }
  
  return result;
}
```